# How do I use a storyboard for more than 1 target object?

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a c# class, let's call it `TwoButtonsHolder`. In this class, I have 2 `UIElements` I wanna animate using StoryBoards. Let's call them `ButtonA` and `ButtonB`. Because I wanna have the both of them animate at the same time, I decided to put all their animations in one Storyboard object (or is there a better way?). So right now I'm trying to create the storyboard object in code behind, but I am stuck at the part where I have to define the target property. Normally when I declare animations I use code like this to set the property

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation,
                             new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
```

now I have the UIElement within the target Object of the type TwoButtonsHolder. How do I create a storyboard and set the animation target property to `TwoButtonsHolder.ButtonA.UIElement.OpacityProperty`? Is this bad design for using a single storyboard to animate multiple objects in order to have animation that runs at the same time? (Just FYI, I wanna try this in code behind, don't wanna go into XAML yet because I find it too complicated and hard to learn IMHO). Thank you

Edit: Just wanna add that the 2 buttons have different animations, the only reason I'm putting them in the same storyboard is for them to start animating at the same time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is absolutely no bad design to have animations for multiple objects in one Storyboard.

You would write it somehow like this:

```
var animationA = new DoubleAnimation(...);
Storyboard.SetTarget(animationA, ButtonA);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationA, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

var animationB = new DoubleAnimation(...);
Storyboard.SetTarget(animationB, ButtonB);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationB, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

var storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(animationA);
storyboard.Children.Add(animationB);
storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens, but I don't know how to set the `PropertyPath` from the parent object. If I set it as `PropertyPath(TwoButtonsHolder.UIElement.OpacityProperty)` there will be error. Can you help me with the PropertyPath?

Comment: I just tried again and it keeps showing `"Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'UIElement.OpacityProperty'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."`

Comment: The property should be set as shown in my answer. It is initialized from the [UIElement.OpacityProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacityproperty.aspx) field. There is no such thing as a `TwoButtonsHolder.UIElement.OpacityProperty`.

Comment: You can also pass "Opacity" as a string to the PropertyPath constructor.

Comment: Are `ButtonA` and `ButtonB` UIElements?

Comment: @Clements Ok I've changed my `Storyboard.Begin(myTwoButtonsHolder)` to `Storyboard.Begin();`, now there's a different error `No target was specified for 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'.`

Comment: @Clemens Yes They are UIElements, and MyTwoButtonsHolder is derived from `DependencyObject`

Comment: Did you call `Storyboard.SetTarget(...)` as shown in my answer?

Comment: @Clemens Yes. I copied the code and change it to `                var da = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, Duration);
                Storyboard.SetTarget(da, myButton);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("UIElement.OpacityProperty"));
                Storyboard.Children.Add(da);
                Storyboard.Begin();`

Comment: Is it possible the error is because I named my StoryBoard object also as StoryBoard?

Comment: You must not set the property path argument in quotes. Eiter you write `new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty)` or `new PropertyPath("Opacity")`.